# &no always being displayed as special character

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

This may be the silliest question, I've ever asked, but I just can't find a solution...

I'm working with email notifications, but instead of writing the notifications, I want to show the users their notification list on my site.

now in my emails, i'm using:

```
<iframe width=100%; height:100% src='http://www.mysite.com/newsfeed/index.php?email=true&user=".$to_id."&notification_type=messages'/>
```

but my email client (mail.app) keeps turning the **&no** in &notification_type into a special character...

any ideas that don't involve changing the $_GET variable in my index.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use html special chars in urls too:

Use `<a href=".&amp;user=....&amp;notification_type=.." >`

Answer (score 0):

Use this `&amp;` in place of this `&`